# What do these numbers mean in my Flask application's log output?

Tags: python, logging, flask, wsgi, eventlet

I have a Flask application that runs with `Flask-SocketIO`. I recently installed `eventlet` in order to improve performance and utilise the web socket protocol.

My HTTP logs started having **2 additional parameters** at the end (after the status code):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2019 15:27:58] "GET /supported_countries HTTP/1.1" 200 488 0.019999
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2019 15:27:58] "GET /specializations HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.003003
```

In this case it's the numbers `488 0.019999` and `381 0.003003`.

I am assuming it's the **size** of the response and the **time** it took to complete the request?

### What are they? (and can I configure what request info is logged?)

Here is my `application.py`

```
from my_app import create_app, socketio
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host=app.config.get('APP_HOST'), 
                 log_output=app.config.get('LOGGING', False))
```

Again, please note that this was not happening prior to the installaiton of `eventlet`. Flask-SocketIO atuomatically detects that I have it installed and selects it (emphasis mine):

> The extension automatically detects which asynchronous framework to use based on what is installed. **Preference is given to eventlet**, followed by gevent. For WebSocket support in gevent, uWSGI is preferred, followed by gevent-websocket. **If neither eventlet nor gevent are installed, then the Flask development server is used**.

So the Flask dev server does not output these numbers, whilst the eventlet-configured server does.

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: @MohammadrezaMirhajianmoghadam I added the relevant code and more info regarding the extensions that are causing this.

Comment: Is this a problem? :-)

Comment: @Kris, not really, but it did mess up my Grep Console setup a little bit. I would certainly like to know what those numbers mean though.